# How to pass a singleton object to a partial in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming, singleton-methods

I have the following code in my controller

```
@current_chat = current_user.sent_messages
                         .where("created_at > ? and receiver_id = ?", current_user.current_sign_in_at, current_chat[:receiver_id].to_i)
                         .select("body, created_at").each { |message| message.instance_eval { def type; @type end; @type = 'sent' } }
```

And I'm passing the @current_chat object to a partial like so:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/chat_form', locals: { messages: @current_chat } %>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
singleton can't be dumped
```

At the first line in ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier#generate

```
def generate(value)
  data = ::Base64.strict_encode64(@serializer.dump(value))
  "#{data}--#{generate_digest(data)}"
end
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this

```
@serializer.dump(value)
```

This is causing the error. Read this link, its all about using singletons in ruby.
[link](http://www.devalot.com/articles/2008/09/ruby-singleton)

Comment: I'm not using it.This is rails source code. I've mentioned the module and class in the question. Any way to avoid it?

Comment: Once you’ve created a singleton class for an object you can no longer use Marshal.dump on that object. The marshal library does not support objects with singleton classes.

Comment: Actually, I want to 'tag' the records returned by the query `current_user.sent_messages` as 'sent'. Any idea how to do this without using instance_eval?